# Html (get) form RGB selector on Arduino

Tags: html, css

**The project**

I'm making a RGB-Ledstrip controller based on Arduino.
I currently have the hardware working, but I would want to make it controllable through a page (ideally) hosted on Arduino.

**The problem**

My Arduino can currently generate this HTML, however, it would be practical if the user had some type of feedback.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
       <form method="get" action="?">
          R <input type="range" name="R" value="0" min="0" max="255"></br>
          G <input type="range" name="G" value="0" min="0" max="255"></br>
          B <input type="range" name="B" value="0" min="0" max="255"></br>
          <div style="width:100px;height:100px; background:#f00;"></div>
          <input type="submit" value="Send color">
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm looking for a way to display the chosen color.
Ideally it should make the square colored in the way the sliders are set.
So, if I could get the current slider values and put them as the background color, I would be set.

But, as far as my knowledge goes, this is simply not the way HTML works.

**The question(s)**

- Can I use CSS to obtain the current slider values and apply it as the boxs' color?

**What I tried**

My best shot at it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
       <form method="get" action="?">
          R <input type="range" id="R" name="R" value="0" min="0" max="255"></br>
          G <input type="range" id="G" name="G" value="0" min="0" max="255"></br>
          B <input type="range" id="B" name="B" value="0" min="0" max="255"></br>
          <div style="width:100px;height:100px; background: rgb(attr(R), attr(G),attr(B));"></div>
          <input type="submit" value="Send color">
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it simply does not resolve the "rgb()" function. I think I'm close, but not yet there.

*Please mind that the memory of the Arduino is very limited, that's why I try to make it as minimal as possible. It could easily be done in Javascript, with a fancy colorwheel etc. but that will probably take too much bytes of memory.*

Comment: I know you asked for no javascript, so I will not post this as a answer, but I don't think it's otherwise achievable in a HTML-enviroment. It can however, as you said, be done with very simple javascript. Made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9h29ujjk/

Comment: @Imbue I was indeed wondering if it could be done just in CSS, since I think I'm quite on track with my last example, though I'm not really that good at CSS.

Your javascript example is actually pretty small, I believe it would be able to fit on the Arduino. But wouldn't it be more logical to loop through "inputs" and check if it's of type "range" and then set the event listener?

Comment: Actually you may just post that as an answer. It does add around 500 bytes though, but I do have a 32kBytes of program memory, so if the rest (networking) doesn't take that much, it may just fit (and be good enough).

Comment: @Imbue I've found a way to minimize the javascript (while keeping it somewhat readable), you can post your answer (and I will accept it), but I'll add my version of the code to it, if you don't mind. I'd want to refrain from creating an answer myself, since it doesn't give you any credits (and I would've somewhat stolen the answer).

Comment: Thanks, that is much appreciated. I'm very interested in seeing your solution too, so please add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's not achievable in plain HTML/CSS, I have created a javascript, with the use of the provided HTML instead, as it is the only solution I know of.

```
<form method="get" action="?">
      R <input type="range" id="r" name="R" value="0" min="0" max="255">
      G <input type="range" id="g" name="G" value="0" min="0" max="255">
      B <input type="range" id="b" name="B" value="0" min="0" max="255">
      <div id="color" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></div>
      <input type="submit" value="Send color">
 </form>
```

The script simply takes the different rangevalues when the range changes and edits the preview-box color accordingly.

```
var inputs=document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    i=0,
    color = document.getElementById('color');
do{
    switch(inputs[i].type){
    case 'range':
      inputs[i].addEventListener('change', onChange)
    break;
  }
}
while(inputs[++i])

function onChange(){
    var r = document.getElementById('r').value,
    g = document.getElementById('g').value,
    b = document.getElementById('b').value;

    color.style.background = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
}
```

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9h29ujjk/) for reference.

Comment: Your comment/answer on using javascript helped me to find out that "using minimal javascript" it's actually also possible to make this. I've "minimized" your example (and made it a bit more logical) in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mc8otx4p/

Comment: Great glad it helped and your solution works great, although inline-scripting isn't too pretty, it doesen't make the performance worse, probably a little better. You can for a very small extra boost in performance wrap the document in a variable (var doc = document;) to no call the document four times in a row.

Comment: I agree that inline scripting isn't very nice, though, on an Arduino it makes a lot of sense. It actually has no complete webserver with files. It just responds with a single long HTML "string" which happens to be a full file.

Comment: You can watch a video of the "finished project" on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aode4N_aRc

Thank you for contributing (: